HWiNFO64 CSV LOG file shows framerate value as "159.08.00" and in function field as "06/01/1900 15.08.00". Want the actual value to be "159,08"
I have opened the HWiNFO CSV log file in excel and used the "Text to Columns" feature to sort the data. Now I have my Framerate values in a single column but they show e.g "159.08.00" in the column and "06/01/1900 15.08.00" in the function field. How could I change a column of these values to "159,08" so I could calculate the average for example. The last .00 values are 00 in all. I found that AMD adrenaline software had the values as "159.08" and in that case the "Find & Select" and "Replace..." feature worked but now when I change all the . to , the "159.08.00" value changes to "06/01/1900  15,08,00".

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

As has been noted ad nauseum in this and related forums, OPENing CSV files in Excel can be fraught with problems unless you have limited data sets. You are much better off IMPORTing csv files using either the legacy import wizard, or Power Query (Get&Transform => From Text). By doing that, you can define the data types properly at the time of import, and not run into the problem you have.

Use a text editor to replace .00 with nothing, and . with ,

Could you please tell us what does 'function field' mean? Is it formula bar? Using Text Editor can clear some formatting, you may try it and check whether it gets real "159.08.00", and then use Text to Columns function again.

By function field I mean formula bar. With Ron Rosenfeld advice I was able fix the issue. Using the Excels in-built Get Data -> From TXT/CSV I was able to load and transform the data correctly. Thank you!
